# Multiplicacion horas x numero

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo el caso de un tiempo trabajado y su sueldo por horas. Necesito calcular cuanto han cobrado:

```
SELECT '07:45'::time as horas_trabajadas,
        8.45::numeric(18,2) as precio_hora,
        '07:45'::interval * 8.45 as total_dia
```

Aquí el tema esta en que me `total_dia` sale como:

> 0 years 0 mons 0 days 65 hours 29 mins 15.00 secs

Y necesito que me diga lo que ha ganado el trabajador. En este caso seria: `7.75*8.44 = 65.4875`

Creo que tiene que ser sencillo, pero no veo la solución

Aquí tenéis un [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/24242) con la consulta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes:

```
SELECT
    '07:45'::time as horas_trabajadas,
    8.45::numeric(18,2) as precio_hora,
    (extract(epoch from '07:45'::interval) / 3600) * 8.45 as total_dia;
```

Lo encontré en el otro SO en ingles:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952493/how-do-i-convert-an-interval-into-a-number-of-hours-with-postgres

Comment: Ojo! lo acabo de probar, gracias! Al igual se me ocurrire su `epoch` x 3600